# Prevent multiple popups opening on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a website which uses a number of popups to display information. However, when any button is clicked, all the popups will open at once and will cover up the information I want to show.

Below is the code I have so far:

**Javascript:**

(I believe this may be where I have made my error as, when one button is clicked, clicking another button will simply close the popup and will not open a new one as I intended it to.)

```
function deselect(e) {
  $('.pop').slideToggle('normal', function() {
    e.removeClass('selected');
  });
}

$(function() {
  $('#youtube, #youtube-popup').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      deselect($(this));
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('#youtube');
      //      $(this).removeClass('#twitch');
      $('.pop').slideToggle();
    }
    return false;
  });

  $('.close').on('click', function() {
     deselect($(this).closest('#youtube, #youtube-popup'));

    return false;
  });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.messagepop {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
  color: #000000;
  display: none;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  z-index: 50;
  padding: 25px 25px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.messagepop p,
.messagepop.div {
  padding-top: 200px;
}
```

**HTML:**

I may have over-complicated this part which may have lead to further errors.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body bgcolor="grey">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <br>
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <div class="hover">
          <img href="" id="youtube" src="http://geniussys.com/img/placeholder/blogpost-avatar-50x50.png" padding="1px 1px 1px 1px"></div>
        <div class="hover">
          <img href="" id="twitter" src="http://geniussys.com/img/placeholder/blogpost-avatar-50x50.png" padding="1px 1px 1px 1px"></div>
        <div class="hover">
          <img href="" id="facebook" src="http://geniussys.com/img/placeholder/blogpost-avatar-50x50.png" padding="1px 1px 1px 1px"></div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="messagepop pop">
    <div id="youtube-popup">
       <font size=5><b>Text 1</b>
    <br><font size=2>
  Text 1.
    <br><font size=5><b>Text 2</b>
    <br><font size=2>Text 2.
  </font>

  <div class="messagepop pop">
    <div id="twitter-popup">
    <font size=5><b>Text 3</b>
    <br><font size=2>Text 3.
    <br><font size=5><b>Text 4</b>
    <br><font size=2>Text 4.
    <br><font size=5><b>Text 5</b>
    <br><font size=2>Text 5.
  </font></div>
  </div>

  <div class="messagepop pop">
    <div id="facebook-popup">
      <font size=5><b>Text 6</b>
    <br><font size=2>Text 6.
  </font></div>
  </div>
```

If you need more information, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said, your HTML is not well formed at all([ul] tag must have [li] children, [font] is unsupported in HTML5), and your javascript is...bad!

You can achieve desired behavior with a single function

```
  $('img').on('click', function() {
    $('.pop.active').each(function() { $(this).slideToggle();  $(this).removeClass('active'); $('#' + $(this).data('refli')).removeClass('selected'); });
    var myId= $('#' + $(this).attr('id'));
    var myPop= $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '-popup');
    myId.addClass('selected');
    myPop.addClass('active');
    myPop.slideToggle();
  });
```

[Here you can find a quick sample](https://jsfiddle.net/berets/u448h12a/)

Comment: Hi. This works great, thank you! Is there any way to make it so that when you click on a button which is already active it closes the popup?

Answer (score 0):

When using `<font>` tag, you should close him aswell. When using `<ul>` tag, inside it, you must have `<li>` tags. Your jquery code is a mess, sorry. I write a much easier example for what you were probably looking.

Check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xtmzq2pn/1/

```
$(".box").on("click",function(){
if($(this).is("#square1")){
$("#text1").slideToggle();
$("#text2").css("display","none");
$("#text3").css("display","none");
}else if($(this).is("#square2")){
$("#text2").slideToggle();
$("#text1").css("display","none");
$("#text3").css("display","none");
}else if($(this).is("#square3")){
$("#text3").slideToggle();
$("#text2").css("display","none");
$("#text1").css("display","none");
}})
```